# How to get the gPRC call status from the balancer

Tags: go, grpc

The balancer interface `Get` method has a `put` function, as one of its returns, that's supposed to be called after the grpc call:

> // The function returns put which is called once the rpc has completed or failed.
>
> // put can collect and report RPC stats to a remote load balancer.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/balancer.go#L74

How do I get the status of the gRPC call (success/failure), and stats?

The use of interceptors is an alternative, but would like to use this method if it is possible to get the status/stats.

Comment: "put" function not implemented for balancer yet, you'll have to write your own implementation

Comment: @MarcelNovy, that's right. but nothing is passed to it. How can I access the status of a grpc call from within the balancer?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, load balancing is still "work in progress" and it's rather experimental than practical usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you cannot access the status/stats in put. There is WIP on collecting stats. Once it is done, you can access them via the context which is the input of Get. ETA is the end of this year.